# Why does number of rows of predictions using predict() on ensemble model exceed dataframe rows?

Tags: r, caret, ensemble-learning

1. I am using `caretEnsemble::caretList()` to train several different models on a list of 10 randomly drawn subsamples of 80% of iris data with the remaining 20% as holdout.
2. Subsequently, I use `caretEnsemble::caretEnsemble()` on the list of models to get a glm-weighted average across all separate algorithms.
3. Finally, I use caret::predict() to extract the predictions of each separate model as well as the ensemble, hoping to be able to store the predictions in the iris dataset.

## Problem

While the number of predictions returned by predict() on the individual models equals the number of rows from iris (N = 150), the same does not apply to the ensemble, where predict() yields 280 rows.

## Illustration

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

# Seed
set.seed(123)

# Data
datasets::iris %>% 
  select(1:3) -> iris

# Folds for training (80% of iris, 10 resamples)
folds <- createDataPartition(iris$Petal.Length, times = 10, p = 0.8, list = TRUE)

# Train controls
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                              index = folds,
                              savePredictions = TRUE)

# List of models (generalized linear model, random forest)
models <- caretList(iris[,1:2], iris[,3], methodList=c("glm", "rf"),
                    trControl = train.control, 
                    tuneLength = 10)

# Option 1: No specific train controls
ens <- caretEnsemble(models)

ens$ens_model$resample %>% nrow() # 25

predict(ens$ens_model) # 280

# Option 2: Train controls same as in caretList
ens.2 <- caretEnsemble(models, trControl = train.control)

ens.2$ens_model$resample %>% nrow() # 10

predict(ens.2$ens_model) # 280

# Compare to individual models
predict(models$glm) # 150

predict(models$rf) # 150

iris$pred_glm <- predict(models$glm)
```

## Question(s)

1. Could anyone explain to me why predict() consistently yields more rows (N = 280) than I have rows in my dataframe (N = 150)?
2. Are there any serious flaws in my approach of extracting predictions from my separate models and storing them in the original dataset or is that approach methdologically sound? In other words, am I exclusively storing predictions on my test sets in iris or am I accidentally also storing predictions on my test rows in iris (see: last line of code)?

Comment: If you see `?predict` function it accepts a model object and you can provide a `newdata` argument to specify the dataset for which you want predictions. So, if you use `predict(ens, newdata = iris)`, it gives 150 predictions only based on ensemble of glm and rf. If you want individual model wise predictions, you can use `predict(ens$models$glm, newdata = iris)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Although I still don't quite know why predict(models$glm) yields the correct number of rows and predict(ens$ens_model) yields N = 280 rows.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that my approach of using predict() in that way is really doing what I think it does, i.e., to extract the predictions from the individual and ensemble models for the test set(s). ...

Comment: To clarify: I THINK that what I want is the predicted values for my various holdout samples. If there was only one train and one testset, the predictions would be the size of the testset (e.g. 20%). Since I created my folds in such a way that there's overlap and each observation will end up in train and test at least several times, I should be able to extract predictions that are purely based on the holdout. Alternatively, I could, as you suggested, apply the trained model on "newdata" (which would be the whole dataset that I used for CV) and would therefore lump together train & test, right?